# The header color should change to some other color

Tags: css, css-float

I have a table data that doesnt have width. when i have multiple columns when they touches browsers end, the header color should change to some other color. Is this possible with css? or with css expressions?  http://jsfiddle.net/AGrJJ/

Comment: Do you want to change the color on some specific condition or simply without any condition?

Comment: can we use the condition as css expression in css

Comment: Not in css but with javascript.

Comment: but i dont want to add any javascript. i can use in css expression from css.

Comment: Then I think you can try this http://www.conditional-css.com/

Comment: Other than that you can define a class for your "th" tags and apply the css "background-color" property to that class.

Comment: There is no such thing as: 'Do that if this is touching browser end' in CSS. You have to use JS: Get all the table headers; look, if the right end is farther to the right than the window's right side; and than change the CSS (either class or style directly). I see no other way

Comment: [Media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) can help in some cases (dimension-related, but not for inter-element alignment cases.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple fiddle with jquery JS

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/AGrJJ/2/

```
​$('th').each(function() {
    if ($(this).offset().left + $(this).width() > $('body').width()) {
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
    }
})​​
```

Comment: I need only from css. No another scripts

Comment: I said, it's not possble with css only in my comment to the question